$B(\mathcal{H}) $ can occur as a quotient by a primal ideal.
I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $B(\mathcal{H}) $ be the space of bounded operators. Then there exist a $C^{\ast}$-algerba $\mathcal{A}$ and a primal ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $B(\mathcal{H}) =\mathcal{A}/I$

Follows easily by taking $\mathcal{A}$ the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of all sequences of elements in $B(\mathcal{H}) $ which are norm convergent to an element in $B(\mathcal{H})$  and $I$ the ideal of null sequences.

Can someone please explain this proof?

Recall that an ideal $I$ of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra is called a primal ideal if whenever $J_1J_2... J_n=\{0\}$ for some ideals $J_i$, then at least one $J_i$ is contained in $I$.

Can you include a definition of primal ideals in a $C^\ast$-algebra? Might be because different authors use different terminology or something, but I’ve never seen the terminology primal ideals being used in the context of $C^\ast$-algebras before.

The proof itself is easy enough though. $A$, the collection of all norm convergent sequences in $B(H)$, is a $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}, B(H))$. The map $\pi: A \to B(H)$, defined by sending a sequence to its norm limit, is a surjective $\ast$-homomorphism, whose kernel is exactly $I$, the ideal of null sequences (that is, sequences converging to $0$). Thus, $B(H) \simeq A/I$.

@DavidGao: I have included the definition. Thanks.

The proof of the assertion $B(H) \simeq A/I$ is already in my comment, which I’ll copy here: $A$, the collection of all norm convergent sequences in $B(H)$, is a $C^\ast$-subalgebra of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N}, B(H))$. The map $\pi: A \to B(H)$, defined by sending a sequence to its norm limit, is a surjective $\ast$-homomorphism, whose kernel is exactly $I$, the ideal of null sequences (that is, sequences converging to $0$). Thus, $B(H) \simeq A/I$.
As for why $I$ is primal, it is a general fact that primitive ideals are prime, from which it follows it is primal, according to the definition you wrote down. Here is a proof, simplified for this specific case:
It suffices to show that, if $J_1J_2 = \{0\}$, then one of $J_i$ is contained in $I$. Let $\pi: A \to B(H)$ be the surjective $\ast$-homomorphism constructed before. Assume $J_2 \not\subset I$. Then $\pi(J_2)$ is a nonzero ideal in $B(H)$ as $\ker(\pi) = I$, whence $K(H) \subset \varphi(J_2)$. $J_1J_2 = \{0\}$ then implies, after applying $\pi$, that $\pi(J_1)H = \pi(J_1)K(H)H \subset \pi(J_1)\pi(J_2)H = \{0\}$, so $\pi(J_1) = \{0\}$, i.e., $J_1 \subset I$.
